Raydium error: Transaction instruction index 0 has undefined program id
I'm trying to create a new MarketId using makeCreateMarketInstrucrion in '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2'.
But the program gives an error:
Error: Transaction instruction index 0 has undefined program id

async function create_market_id(token, mainKeypair, connection) {
    let transaction = new Transaction();

    const dexProgramId =  DEVNET_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET;
    const wallet = mainKeypair.publicKey;
    const basemint = token;
    const quotemint = SOLMint;

    const market = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: dexProgramId });
    const baseVault = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: dexProgramId });
    const quoteVault = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID });
    const requestQueue = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: dexProgramId });
    const eventQueue = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: dexProgramId });
    const bids = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: dexProgramId });
    const asks = new generatePubKey({ fromPublicKey: wallet, programId: dexProgramId });
    const feeRateBps = 0;
    const quoteDustThreshold = new BN(100);
    const baseLotSize = new BN(Math.round(10 ** 9 * 1));
    const quoteLotSize = new BN(Math.round(1 * 10 ** 9 * 0.01));
    function getVaultOwnerAndNonce() {
      const vaultSignerNonce = new BN(0);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
      while (true) {
        try {
          const vaultOwner = PublicKey.createProgramAddressSync(
            [market.publicKey.toBuffer(), vaultSignerNonce.toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8)],
            dexProgramId,
          );
          return { vaultOwner, vaultSignerNonce };
        } catch (e) {
          vaultSignerNonce.iaddn(1);
          if (vaultSignerNonce.gt(new BN(25555))) throw Error("find vault owner error");
        }
      }
    };
    const { vaultOwner, vaultSignerNonce } = getVaultOwnerAndNonce();

   
    const instruction = await makeCreateMarketInstruction({
      connection: connection,
      wallet: wallet,
      marketInfo: {
        programId: dexProgramId,
        id: market,
        baseMint: basemint,
        quoteMint: quotemint,
        baseVault,
        quoteVault,
        vaultOwner,
        requestQueue,
        eventQueue,
        bids,
        asks,

        feeRateBps,
        quoteDustThreshold,
        vaultSignerNonce,
        baseLotSize,
        quoteLotSize,
      }
    });
    transaction.add(instruction);
    const marketId = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, [mainKeypair])

    console.log("market_id: ", marketId);
    
}


I think you use the API of the SDK in "a wrong" way. The instruction object you get from the makeCreateMarketInstruction(...) is not a set of instructions that can be passed to Transaction.add(). I believe there is a type mismatch.
Consider the structure of the returned object
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2/blob/master/src/raydium/marketV2/instrument.ts#L219
And consider checking how the SDK is used and integrated into other Solana clients
https://github.com/Shiny0805/Solana-Token-Dist/blob/main/src/create_market.js#L17-L30
or
https://github.com/blockworks-foundation/mango-v4-ui/blob/3394732869731b4f06f2b3dea18b90471e6ab0d9/utils/governance/market/createOpenBookMarket.ts#L19
https://github.com/blockworks-foundation/mango-v4-ui/blob/3394732869731b4f06f2b3dea18b90471e6ab0d9/components/modals/CreateOpenbookMarketModal.tsx#L107

If I use one of these clients, where will I need to pass the instruction that I will receive using one of these methods?

I meant to check how the SDK is used at other places, in other projects, in other clients. I think you can check the code and copy and paste part of it to get your example working.

Thanks, I've solved this with your help!
